# Elastic search - no hit though there should be result

Tags: elasticsearch

I've encountered the following problem with Elastic search, does anyone know where should I troubleshoot?

I'm happily retrieving result with the following query:
{

```
"query" : {
    "match" : { "name" : "A1212001" }
}
```

}

But when I refine the value of the search field "name" to a substring, i've not no hit?
{

```
"query" : {
    "match" : { "name" : "A12120" }
}
```

}

"A12120" is a substring of already hit query "A1212001"

Comment: You want to search for `A12120*`??

Comment: The version I used is: elasticsearch-2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have too many documents, you can go with a [`regexp` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)

```
POST /index/_search
{
  "query" :{
    "regexp":{
        "name": "A12120.*"
    }
  }
}
```

or even a [`wildcard` one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

```
POST /index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard" : { "name" : "A12120*" }
  }
}
```

However, as @Waldemar suggested, if you have many documents in your index, the best approach for this is to use an [`EdgeNGram` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) since the above queries are not ultra-performant.

First, you define your index settings like this:

```
PUT index
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_analyzer" : {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "edge_tokens",
                    "filter": ["lowercase"]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer" : {
                "edge_tokens" : {
                    "type" : "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram" : "1",
                    "max_gram" : "10",
                    "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when indexing a document whose name field contains `A1212001`, the following tokens will be indexed: `A`, `A1`, `A12`, `A121`, `A1212`, `A12120`, `A121200`, `A1212001`. So when you'll search for `A12120` you'll find a match.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Will it be bad if I create custom analyzor, so that all permutation of substrings are tokenized? e.g. A, A1, A12, A121, A1212, A12120, A121200, A1212001, 1, 12, 121, 1212.... 'coz i would like to do substring matching, as long as the field contains my query string, then it should be hit.

Comment: No worries, in that case simply use `nGram` instead of `edgeNGram` and it will also index all substrings. That's the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) this query will check for terms inside lucene and your term is **A1212001** if you need to find a part of your term do you can use a [Regex Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) but you need know that will be there some internal impacts using regex because the shard will check in all of your terms.

If you need a more "professional" way to search a part of a term do you can use [NGrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)